# Резиновая верстка

Tags: вёрстка, css

Доброго времени суток! есть сайт с резиновой версткой, при моем разрешении 1600Х900 меню отображается ровно, но если экран более "квадратный", меню разъезжается вот так:
[image]

как это исправить?
Меню задано списком ul. у ul display:block; у li display:inline-block

Comment: Как вариант:

1. Каждую строку (т.е. три блока в строке) вложить в отдельный div.
2. Каждый блок в строке выровнять по центру

Можно сделать через display:table/table-cell. [ПРИМЕР](http://jsfiddle.net/6eGd2/2/)

UPD: пока писал вы обновили вопрос. Может тогда пример выложите на том же jsFiddle? У вас проблема просто с тем, что где-то одна строка, где-то две строки. Если бы везде было в две строки - смещения бы не было.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В принципе как бы понятно то, что блоки по умолчанию имеют позиционирование по `baseline` относительно блока контейнера. Для того чтобы это исправить в `css` есть свойство `vertical-align: top;` это свойство работает еще в `css v1,` т.е. даже в ie6. все что вам нужно сделать:
У блоков `li` выставить вертикальное выраванивание `vertical-align: top;` и `display: inline-block;` он у вас выставлен, для `ie6` придется поставить `display: inline;` и `zoom: 1;` но в принципе  блоки выровнять вам удастся без особых проблем.